# replacing two spaces with an 'x' using only putchar and getchar

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

This program should replace two spaces with an x, using only getchar() and putchar(). My approach was to store the space in a buffer and then print it out. But the program replaces every space with an x. Can someone help me out?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 2

char arr[MAX];
int ret = 0;
char second;

int main()
{
  for(int i=0; ; )
  {
    if ( (ret = getchar())!= EOF)  
    {
         putchar(ret);
    }
    if(ret==' '&&second==' ')
    {
      arr[i]=ret;
      arr[i]='x';
      putchar(arr[i]);
    }   
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need another index variable for the array, otherwise indexing with `i` will leave gaps. And note that `arr[i]='x';` overwrites `arr[i]=ret;`

Comment: index i to store and for example index r to output?

Comment: I would think your code prints out every character that comes in, _and_ prints an 'x' after each space. And also never leaves the input loop.

Comment: If you have a one-character buffer, it doesn't need to be an array. You can just declare one more variable. (Though I don't know what you would use it for.)

Comment: @arndt yeah thats what it does but if the intput is a a will be a  xa and it should be axa

Comment: sry guys i just realised the title dosen't match the description its supposed to replace two spaces with an x

Comment: i have edited my code

Answer (score 3):

When you read a character, first check if it's a space.  If not, just print it.  If it is read another character, then if the second is a space print an `x` otherwise print a space and the character you just read.

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c != ' ') {
        putchar(c);
    } else {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == EOF) {
            putchar(' ');
        } else if (c == ' ') {
            putchar('x');
        } else {
            putchar(' ');
            putchar(c);
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but I dont really understand why we putchar(' ') when c==EOF

Comment: @momonosuke At that point you've reached the end of the stream, but there's still a space you've read that you haven't printed yet.  So it needs to be printed there.

Comment: and the else if statement should only take place if the if statement above is false. I have trouble understanding why the else if is the second space

Comment: @momonosuke You want to print an `x` if you read two spaces in a row.    In the `else` section of the outer `if` you've read one space.  When the `else if (c == ' ')` clause is true that means you've read two spaces, so print `x` instead of those spaces.

Comment: oh now i get it thanks and what aobut if i want to modify the code so that it replaces three spaces with an x. I just want to know the approach